# Linux equivalent of Unix who -m command, to show original user ID before su?

Tags: linux, security, unix, login-script, identity-management

I'm trying to find a Linux equivalent of running `who -m` in Unix. In Unix, `who -m` gives the first user ID you used to log in, before starting any new shell sessions through `su`, etc.

The `-m` switch to `who` has a different effect in Linux, and I'm unable to find anything relevant to my needs in the man pages so far.

Comment: I FOUND A WORKAROUND! `ls -l \`tty\` | awk '{print $3}'` returns the expected output consistently across Linux systems, while `who -m` works on some but not others.

Comment: Ideally I would still like to know a `who` way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: My answer (who am i) is correct, your terminal is either broken or not configured correctly to support the functionality.

Based on the comments, I've done some more research and I asked [a friend](https://serverfault.com/users/75118/matthew-ife) to help. You don't say which terminal you are using but it's likely doing the same thing as gnome-terminal.

In respect of gnome-terminal<sup>*</sup> when the terminal is started, it does not update the utmp file. This appears to be a design decision. Later when who  reads utmp to find out the relevant information it's not there so it just exits and prints nothing.

<sup>*</sup> I tries xterm, konsole and ssh to various distros.

---

You want `who am i` which prints the invoking user as opposed to `whoami` which tells you the username of the current effective user

> If given two non-option arguments, 'who' prints only the entry for
>   the user running it (determined from its standard input), preceded by
>   the hostname.  Traditionally, the two arguments given are 'am i', as in
>   'who am i'.

That is buried in `info coreutils 'who invocation'` So interestingly (on a linux coreutils based system) `who xyzzy plugh` works as well.

Comment: Logged in on my local GNOME console, `who mom likes` prints nothing.

Comment: Thanks! I see now that my Linux sample size should have been larger. I tried a couple more and found one that works in the way you explained: `who am i` and `who -m` both return the same output on that system actually.

However, on the first ones I looked at, they return no output at all.
`root@server:/root $ who am i`
`root@server:/root $ who -m`
`root@server:/root $ which who`
`/usr/bin/who`

Comment: The man page on the systems where it doesn't work shows, for option -m:
`-m     Output only information about the current terminal.` There is no info in the man page for `who am i` on those sytems. `info who` gives the expected info, but it doesn't behave that way when executed.

Comment: The *other* man page (one is man 1p, the other is man 1), shows this for -m: `-m     only hostname and user associated with stdin`. Either way, blank line haha.

Comment: @MichaelHampton `who am i` and `who mom likes` work as expected on C6.8, C7.3 , F25 (knosole) and Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I've looked at the utmp file and I believe you're correct. It is xterm on SLES 11 SP3 however.

Comment: http://www.verycomputer.com/171_ec4226b67f099503_1.htm

Comment: Haven't found a way to get the suggested parm to work on my box. That article is 21 years old... I'm guessing /usr/share/X11/etc/app-defaults/{XTerm, XTerm-Color} have changed since then. I did a good bit of playing with configs in /usr/share/X11/etc and /usr/lib/X11 and couldn't get XTerm to write to utmp. The `+ut` option is supposed to take care of that when passed directly to xterm... I can't find where to set that at login time. I'm ready to cut my losses though & use the workaround I commented on the OP. It would be a pain anyway to implement the xterm config change on 1000s of servers.

Comment: I really appreciate your help on this one. It has definitely been informative.